# Why are there duplicate messages in the Build Output window in VS2015 and VS2017?

Tags: c#, build, duplicates, output, warnings

I created a brand new WPF application.  The only code I added is the code which intentionally generates two warnings as shown below.

Both warnings show up twice in the Build Ouptut window in both Visual Studio 2015 and 2017.

Why is this?

How do I make the warnings only show up once?

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (false) {
            int i = 5;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output (paths shortened for clarity...sorry it's hard to read due to the word wrap...):

1>------ Build started: Project: HelloWorld, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------

1>C:...\HelloWorld\MainWindow.xaml.cs(25,5,25,8): warning CS0162: Unreachable code detected

1>C:...\HelloWorld\MainWindow.xaml.cs(25,9,25,10): warning CS0219: The variable 'i' is assigned but its value is never used

1>C:...\HelloWorld\MainWindow.xaml.cs(25,5,25,8): warning CS0162: Unreachable code detected

1>C:...\HelloWorld\MainWindow.xaml.cs(25,9,25,10): warning CS0219: The variable 'i' is assigned but its value is never used

1>  HelloWorld -> C:...\HelloWorld\bin\Debug\HelloWorld.exe

========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

EDIT:  Here is a link to the full MS Build Output (Output Level: Detailed)

[MS BUild Ouput Trace](http://www.filedropper.com/msbuildoutputdetailedtrace)

Comment: Why are you still using 2017 RC?

Comment: Didn't know there was a later version...I thought VS2017RC was the latest version.  Where do I download VS2017 (non-RC)?

Comment: It was officially released on Match 7th. https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/

Comment: Got it.  Thanks.  Downloading it now.  I'm assuming it also has this same bug since VS2015 had it too, but I will check when I've got it installed.

Comment: There is no simple explanation for this, it certainly is not normal.  You need to show the detailed MSBuild trace.

Comment: @HansPassant: I just edited the bottom of the original post to include a link to the detailed MSBuild trace, per your request.  Thank you!

Comment: I am seeing the same behavior in the latest VS2017 release, did you ever determine the cause?

Comment: I'm having the same behavior in VS2022..